# How do I make a lib module method available project-wide and also specific to a class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example I would like to create a `current_server_host` method that returns the current host the application is currently running from.

lib/utility.rb:

```
module Utility
  def current_server_host
    request.env['HTTP_HOST']
  end
end
```

How do I make it available project-wide where I don't need to include anything but can just call via  `Utility.current_server_host`?

How do I make it specific to the class (model/controller/view) where I do need to call `include`?

Please answer for RoR 3.2+.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Utility methods available as class methods in another class, use extend:

```
class Widget
  extend Utility
end

# provides
Widget.current_server_host
```

A ruby module can extend itself in the same manner in which it can extend classes:

```
module Utility
  extend self

  def current_server_host
    request.env['HTTP_HOST']
  end
end

# provides
Utility.current_server_host
```

If you want to provide Utility methods to instances of a class, use include:

```
class Widget
  include Utility
end

widget = Widget.new
widget.current_server_host
```

Comment: Does using a extend self on a Ruby module (your second block) slow down the project since it is available project-wide?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "slow down" or "project-wide".

Comment: Slow down as in performance degrading and project-wide as in within the RoR project.

Comment: The Utility module is available in the top-level namespace (or project wide) as soon as you load it in your project. As for performance degradation, I wouldn't be worried about it as far is this example is concerned. There are lots of examples out there for doing benchmarking however. You may also want to do some background reading on Ruby does method lookups: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/030-issue-1-method-lookup.html